# Написание метода звонка

Tags: java

Есть два класса:

1. Телефон
2. Станция связи

Как сделать метод который будет звонить между двумя телефонами ( например телефон Nokia и телефон Samsung ) если оба эти телефона прошли регистрацию в станции связи ?

Не могу понять логику. Как сравнить два объекта?

Comment: А откуда 1 телефон "узнает" номер телефона номер 2?

Comment: номера телефона не важны, напиример телефон нокиа и самсунг,если оба прошли регистрацию могут звонить, если только один то ошибка

Comment: наверное, телефон должен обратиться к станции, и попросить соединить.

Comment: Ну хорошо, по названию примерно тоже самое, что и номер телефона, только фирмы скоро кончатся, надо предусмотреть если планируются "конференции". Если "АТС" играет роль справочника, то "Самсунг" запрашивает "Нокию" через АТС. Например, Phone nokia =  ats.get("Nokia"); samsung.CallTo(nokia);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс станции:

```
public class MobileNetworkOperator {
    public int id;

    public String name;

    /**
     * Конструктор оператора
     */
    public MobileNetworkOperator(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Регистрация телефона в сети оператора
     */
    public void registration(Phone phone){
        phone.mobileNetworkOperator = MobileNetworkOperator.this;
    }

    /**
     * Метод звонок между двумя телефонами
     */
    public boolean call(Phone firstPhone, Phone secondPhone){
        if (!firstPhone.equals(secondPhone)){
            return false;  // Если телефоны в разных сетях
        }
        return true;  // Если телефоны в пределах одной сети
    }
}
```

Класс телефон:

```
public class Phone {
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public MobileNetworkOperator mobileNetworkOperator;

    /**
     * Конструктор телефона
     */
    public Phone(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Переопределение метода equals(), для того, что бы можно было сравнивать объекты 
     * (в вашему случае или принадлижать два телефона к одному сотовому оператору)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean isEqual= false;
        if (o != null && o instanceof Phone) {
            if (mobileNetworkOperator == ((Phone)o).mobileNetworkOperator) {
                isEqual = true;
            } else {
                isEqual = false;
            }
        }
        return isEqual;
    }

    /**
     * Переопределение hashCode(), без него, даже если переопределить equals(), 
     * объекты нельзя будет сравнить
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть чуть-чуть расписали основную идею

Comment: добавил комментарии к методам

Answer (score 1):

Я может быть не совсем правильно понял что требуется, но вы можете в MobileNetworkOperator объявить лист с зарегистрированными телефонами и далее просто проверять наличие телефона в листе.

В MobileNetworkOperator:

```
ArrayList<Telephone> telList = new ArrayList<Telephone>();  

public void registration(Telephone telephone) {
    if (telList.indexOf(telephone) == -1)
        telList.add(telephone);
}

public boolean isRegistered(Telephone telephone) {
    return telList.contains(telephone);
}
```

При работе с MobileNetworkOperator:

```
if (mobileNetworkOperator.isRegistered(tel1) && mobileNetworkOperator.isRegistered(tel2)) {
    System.out.println("Два телефона зарегистрированы");
}
```

Comment: метод contains() работать не буде

Comment: @Алексей Соловьев, ArrayList наследуется от интерфейса List. Метод contains() в List использует equals() для сравнения объектов. Если есть какие-то проблемы с методом contains(), то можно переопределить equals() и hashcode(). Подобно тому, как сделали вы в вашем примере.

Comment: тогда да все ок) я напысал классы, а вы создали объекты)